# PowerShell SDK + Remote

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I would like to run a powershell (.ps1) script on a remote machine, from a .NET program.
The remote machine is set up correctly, I can connect to it from a PowerShell console.

The run script code is the following (using System.Management.Automation, from PowerShell.SDK.7.2.0-Preview.4 nuget package)

```
public static void RunScript(string scriptFile, string remoteHost, string remoteUser, SecureString remotePassword)
{
    PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(remoteUser, remotePassword);
    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(false, remoteHost, 5985, "/wsman", 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", credential);
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        runspace.Open();
        try
        {
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();
            shell.Runspace = runspace;
            shell.Commands.AddScript(scriptFile, false);
            Collection<PSObject> results = shell.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            runspace.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The remote host, and the username/password credentials are correct (I can connect to the remote machine with the exact same credentials from the PowerShell console)
The CreateRunspace going fine. But the shell.Invoke() does nothing. No exceptions, no result (results contains 0 elements)
If I run the exact same code without the runspace assignment (so the PowerShell usign a default, local runspace), the Invoke() method runs fine, and the result collection is correct.

Has anybody has an idea what should I look for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there anything in the error stream?

Comment: @boxdog, thanks for the heads up! Now, that I'm subscribed to the Error stream, I got valuable information on the situation, now it's working!